# I have Office 2010 and I'm looking for slanted type

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I'm trying to use a graphic type - slanted - curved - special shape.  Can I do this?  Where can I access sloping or curved type?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about WordArt? If so, it's under the Insert tab, under WordArt. Select a type style, and type the text you want. Then, go to the "Drawing Tools - Format" tab (it has an orange highlight above it) to change the formatting. If you want it to have a curve or be slanted, go to "Text Effects -> Transform"; there are a bunch of options there.